# Selenium Proxy with Google chrome portable

Tags: java, selenium-chromedriver

I want to use portable google chrome for my selenium testing. I am using `DesiredCapabilities` object to set `proxy` in browser.

```
Proxy seleniumProxy = ClientUtil.createSeleniumProxy(proxy);

DesiredCapabilities capabilities = new DesiredCapabilities();
capabilities.setCapability(CapabilityType.PROXY, seleniumProxy);
```

And for using portable Google chrome i am using this code.

```
ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
options.setBinary("C:\\Selenium\\Browsers\\GoogleChromePortable\\GoogleChromePortable.exe");
driver = new ChromeDriver(options);
```

Now the problem is the constructor of `ChromeDriver` dont have option for creating driver object using both `DesiredCapabilities`  as well as  `proxy`. i.e. either i can apply proxy or i can use portable chrome.

I want something like this

```
new ChromeDriver(capabilities ,options);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a way

```
DesiredCapabilities capabilities = new DesiredCapabilities();
capabilities.setCapability(CapabilityType.PROXY, seleniumProxy);

ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
options.setBinary("D:\\m_ali\\GoogleChromePortable\\GoogleChromePortable.exe");
capabilities.setCapability(ChromeOptions.CAPABILITY, options);

System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "D:\\m_ali\\chromeDriver\\chromedriver_2.27win32\\chromedriver.exe");

driver = new ChromeDriver(capabilities);
```